# Get close, minimize, and maximize in Chrome to appear on the right side in Freya?

Tags: google-chrome

I can go into Freya's Tweaks in Settings to have Close, Minimize, and Maximize appear on the top right of each window, but this does NOT seem to work for Google Chrome. The Close 'X' is still appearing on the upper left of the window even after applying the Tweaks settings.

Any way to change this?

Comment: please [edit] your question, because your accepted answer won't change `close` button to right side. But in your question you have mentioned to change close button as well =)Also there is nothing to worry about using `command` which was tested

Comment: The accepted answer also puts the close button on the right...

Comment: nope, close button still on left,

Comment: see my edit @fuzzybaby can you justify your [comment](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/get-close-minimize-and-maximize-in-chrome-to-appear-on-the-right-side-in-freya?noredirect=1#comment5138_2769) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into google chrome settings and in apperance you will find **use system title bar and borders** check it and that'll do.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I chose this one as the answer because it's a setting in Chrome itself, so I reckon it's a bit safer than running the command line stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have `minimize` , `maximize` and `close` buttons on top right of **chrome** :

Open terminal and run:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

Now restart chrome.

**GUI** method:

Install `gconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Now Open `configuration-editor` --> apps-->metacity--> general, select `button_layout` and right click --> *Edit Key*.

Now add value `:minimize,maximize,close`

[image: Imgur]

**Note** : If you *enable* **use system title bar and borders** It will not work.So make sure that was disabled. I have tested it in freya.

---

*how to rollback*?

Open `configuration-editor` --> `apps` --> `metacity`--> `general`

Now in right side of the window, select  `button_layout` and right-click select `Unset key`.

Now restart chrome.

---

**EDIT**: To give [clarity](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/get-close-minimize-and-maximize-in-chrome-to-appear-on-the-right-side-in-freya?noredirect=1#comment5138_2769)

At first:

[image: Imgur]

---

Adjusting settings-

[image: Imgur]

After **still close button on left**:

[image: Imgur]

---

After executing **command in my answer** :

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This gconf solution doesn't work anymore in Loki - I suspect it's due to something in the newer versions of Chrome/Chromium and perhaps the Aura graphics stack.

Comment: it finally works again in chromium 55

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc to start Task Manager.
When Task Manager opens, locate Desktop Windows Manager, right click it and choose End Task.